# Find the minimum sum between $2$ line segments.

Tags: geometry

We have the following points in the $xOy$ plane:

$$A(0,0) \hspace{2cm} B(2, 0)$$

And the line:

$$ d : x- 2y + 10 = 0$$

I have to find the minimum value of $S(M)$, where:

$$S(M) = MA + MB$$

where $M$ is a point **on** the line $d$.

I tried looking at the graph:

[image]

Which helped me understand the problem better, I need to find where to put the point $M$ on the green line such that the sum $MA + MB$ is at its minimum. So I understood the problem, but I still don't see how I should approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the graph, the mirror image of the origin $A(0,0)$ with respect to the line $x-2y +10=0$ is $A’(-4,8)$.

Thus, the minimum value $S(M)$ is equal to the straight-line distance between $A’$ and $B$, i.e.

$$S(M)=A’B = \sqrt{8^2+6^2}=10$$

and $M$ is the intersection between the given line and $A’B$.

Comment: But I don't understand why is that sum minimum when we consider the mirror image of $A$. Why isn't it minimum when we consider the mirror image of $B$, or why isn't the sum at its minimum when we have neither the mirror image of $A$ or the mirror image of $B$ and the point $M$ is somewhere in between, where it wouldn't form any mirror image points.

Comment: @user1502 - Since AM = A’M due to the mirror image, S(M) = A’M+MB, which varies with the position of the point M. Because the shortest distance between any two points is the straight line contacting the two points, S(M) is minimal if M is on the straight line A’B. You could use The image of B as well and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your equation under a parametric form, for example as the locus of point $M$ with coordinates :

$$M=(x,y)=(2m-10, \ m)$$

Then minimize function :

$$f(m):=MA+MB=\sqrt{(2m-10)^2+m^2}+\sqrt{(2m-10-1)^2+m^2}$$

by solving equation $f'(m)=0$.

A different direction would be to consider that the minimum sum is achieved when incidence angle and reflection angle are equal (see figure).

But you would obtain the same equations as before.[image]